# ORA-08177: can't serialize access for the transaction

Tags: oracle, exception, ora-08177

I am facing the following exception intermittently. I am using the oracle database and not setting any isolation level

ORA-08177: can't serialize access for this transaction

org.springframework.dao.CannotSerializeTransactionException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL []; ORA-08177: can't serialize access for this transaction
; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: ORA-08177: can't serialize access for this transaction
 : java.sql.SQLException: ORA-08177: can't serialize access for this transaction.

I am not setting the isolation level any where so  it should take the default isolation level which is Read_committed.

but if this is the case with oracle database which takes Read committed by default should not throw this exception.

Kindly suggest.I can't share my code as its my company's code.

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22364432/spring-batch-ora-08177-cant-serialize-access-for-this-transaction-when-running

Comment: Give us some code. We can read documentation, but need something practical. Also, which Oracle DB version are you using?