# CannotSerializeTransactionException in Spring Batch's SimpleJobRepository

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

Took my SpringBatch built on Spring Boot project into a higher environment and I am not receiving a odd error:

`Caused by: org.springframework.dao.CannotSerializeTransactionException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [INSERT into BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_PARAMS(JOB_EXECUTION_ID, KEY_NAME, TYPE_CD, STRING_VAL, DATE_VAL, LONG_VAL, DOUBLE_VAL, IDENTIFYING) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]; ORA-08177: can't serialize access for this transaction
; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: ORA-08177: can't serialize access for this transaction`

I was running this against a Oracle database locally which was running:
Oracle Enterprise 11g R2 v11.2.0.3

Put it into our "Test" environment which is running oracle:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

Any idea how to correct this? Want to demo to my team.

Thanks,

Comment: I would also not be opposed to not writing the data to the SPRING BATCH* tables if this is an option. It seemed that once I added oracle as a DS then it started automatically writing the meta data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Batch ORA-08177: can't serialize access for this transaction when running single job, SERIALIZED isolation level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22364432/spring-batch-ora-08177-cant-serialize-access-for-this-transaction-when-running)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like an issue with your transaction isolation. The default is `ISOLATION_SERIALIZABLE` which is fairly aggressive.

Try changing your `isolationLevelForCreate` to `ISOLATION_READ_COMMITTED` in your `JobRepository` and see how that goes.

Comment: I added the below code to my @Configuration file and it worked. `@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfiguration {

    protected JobRepository createJobRepository() throws Exception {
        JobRepositoryFactoryBean factory = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource);
        factory.setTransactionManager(transactionManager);
        factory.setIsolationLevelForCreate("ISOLATION_READ_COMMITTED");
        return factory.getObject();
    }

    @Autowired
    private PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;
`