Spring batch-5 ORA-08177: can't serialize access for this transaction using Oracle database
I am using spring batch 5 using oracle. I have more than 15 batches running using the database. But it shows below error:
            error code [8177]; ORA-08177: can't serialize access for this transaction

        org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [INSERT INTO BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE(JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME, JOB_KEY, VERSION)
            VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
        ]; SQL state [72000]; error code [8177]; ORA-08177: can't serialize access for this transaction

            at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.translateException(JdbcTemplate.java:1573)
            at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:667)
            at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:960)
            at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:1015)
            at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:1020)
            at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcJobInstanceDao.createJobInstance(JdbcJobInstanceDao.java:157)
            at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.createJobExecution(SimpleJobRepository.java:169)
            at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor32.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
            at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
            at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:196)
            at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
            at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
            at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:391)
            at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
            at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
            at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.AbstractJobRepositoryFactoryBean.lambda$getObject$0(AbstractJobRepositoryFactoryBean.java:204)
            at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
            at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:244)
            at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy124.createJobExecution(Unknown Source)
            at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:145)
            at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.TaskExecutorJobLauncher.run(TaskExecutorJobLauncher.java:59)
            at com.citylive.prepaidcard.config.ScheduledJobBean.perform(ScheduledJobBean.java:62)
            at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor36.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
            at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:84)
            at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
            at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:96)
            at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
            at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
            at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
            at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
            at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
            at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
        Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-08177: can't serialize access for this transaction

            at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:629)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:563)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1150)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:770)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:298)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:497)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:151)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1051)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeSQLStatement(OracleStatement.java:1530)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1310)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3745)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3917)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3896)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:991)
            at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61)
            at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
            at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.lambda$update$2(JdbcTemplate.java:965)
            at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:648)
            ... 34 more
        Caused by: Error : 8177, Position : 0, Sql = INSERT INTO BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE(JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME, JOB_KEY, VERSION)
            VALUES (:1 , :2 , :3 , :4 )
        , OriginalSql = INSERT INTO BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE(JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME, JOB_KEY, VERSION)
            VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
        , Error Msg = ORA-08177: can't serialize access for this transaction

            at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:636)
            ... 51 more

Here is my code:

My application.properties:
    spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/mydb
    spring.datasource.username=test
    spring.datasource.password=test124
    db.name=test

    spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
    spring.datasource.hikari.maximumPoolSize=10
    spring.batch.jdbc.initialize-schema=always


My Schedule Run the job:
   @Component
    @Slf4j
    public class MyJobJob {
        @Autowired
        JobLauncher jobLauncher;

        @Autowired
        EftJob2 eftJob;

        @Autowired
        private  JobRepository jobRepository;

        @Scheduled(cron = "0 */2 * * * ?")
        public void perform() throws Exception
        {

            JobExecution execution = null;
            JobExecution lastJobExecutionStep1 = jobRepository.getLastJobExecution("EFT-STEP1", new JobParametersBuilder().toJobParameters());


            if (lastJobExecutionStep1 == null || lastJobExecutionStep1.getStatus().isLessThan(BatchStatus.STARTING)) {
                log.info( "{}  batch step1 {} execution {} Started: ");
                try {

                    JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder()
                            .addLong("startAtEftStep1", System.currentTimeMillis())
                            .toJobParameters();

                    execution = jobLauncher.run(eftJob.createEft(), jobParameters);

                    log.info(" batch {} Step1 existStatus: "+execution.getExitStatus().getExitCode());

                } catch (JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException | JobRestartException |
                         JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException |
                         JobParametersInvalidException ex) {
                    log.error("batch {} Step1 {} execution {} JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException | JobRestartException | JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException | JobParametersInvalidException message: "+ex.getMessage());
                    ex.printStackTrace();

                }catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();


                }
            }else{
                log.info(" batch step1 {} execution {} isRunning: ");
            }

        }
    }


Job:
    @Component
    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    @Slf4j
    public class EftJob2 {
        private final MySummaryRepo approvedTrxSummaryRepo;
        private final MyTransactionRepo corpApprovedTransactionRepo;

        private final EftProcessorStep1 batchProcessorStep1;
        private final EftWriterStep1 batchWriterStep1;


        private final PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;
        private final JobRepository jobRepository;


        @Autowired
        private JobExecutionListenerStep1 jobExecutionListenerStep1;


        @Autowired
        private MySPcall transactionSPcall;


        public Job createEft(){

            return new JobBuilder("EFT-STEP1", jobRepository)
                    .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                    .start(step1())
                    .build();

        }


        private Step step1(){

            return new StepBuilder("step1", jobRepository)
                    .<ApprovedTrxSummery, ApprovedTrxSummery> chunk(10, transactionManager)
                    .reader(new EftReaderStep1(approvedTrxSummaryRepo,corpApprovedTransactionRepo, transactionSPcall))
                    .processor(batchProcessorStep1)
                    .writer(batchWriterStep1)
                    .build();
        }


    }


Batch config:
      @Configuration
      public class BatchBean {
        @Bean
        public EftProcessorStep1 batchProcessorStep1() {
            return new EftProcessorStep1();
        }

        @Bean
        public EftWriterStep1 batchWriterStep1() {
            return new EftWriterStep1();
        }

    }  


Repository:
    @Transactional
    @Repository
    public interface TransactionRepo extends JpaRepository<TransactionEntity, Long> {
        @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM TRANSACTION WHERE STATUS =1 FOR UPDATE ", nativeQuery = true)
        List<TransactionEntity> getbKashTransaction();
    }


Batch Reader:
Read data from repository using ItemReader
    @Slf4j
    public class ReaderStep1 implements ItemReader<TransactionEntity> {
        private Iterator<TransactionEntity> iterator;
        private TransactionSPcall transactionSPcall;
        public ReaderStep1(TransactionRepo transactionRepo, TransactionSPcall transactionSPcall) {
            this.transactionSPcall = transactionSPcall;
           List<TransactionEntity> list = transactionRepo.getbKashTransaction();

            if(!list.isEmpty()){

                this.iterator = list.iterator();

            }
        }

        @Override
        public TransactionEntity read() {

            return (iterator != null && iterator.hasNext()) ? iterator.next() : null;
        }
    }


Batch Processor:
    @Slf4j
    public class ProcessorStep1 implements ItemProcessor<TransactionEntity, TransactionEntity> {
        @Override
        public TransactionEntity process(TransactionEntity item) throws Exception {
               // Logic calling api

            return item;
        }


Batch writer:
    @Slf4j
    public class WriterStep1 implements ItemWriter<TransactionEntity> {


        @Override
        public void write(Chunk<? extends TransactionEntity> chunk) {

            chunk.forEach(item -> {
              // update database 

            });      
        }
    }
    }



It often occur the error.
What is the wrong of my code?
Please help

Problem is about
    @Transactional
    @Repository
    public interface TransactionRepo extends JpaRepository<TransactionEntity, Long> {
        @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM TRANSACTION WHERE STATUS =1 FOR UPDATE ", nativeQuery = true)
        List<TransactionEntity> getbKashTransaction();
    }

You already have @Transactional on top which makes everything transactional and below using FOR UPDATE is SQL level transactions, instead of mixing java and sql level transactions try to keep them in one layer. I would suggest keep all in java. Otherwise this code may break somewhere else.
And define isolation level like below or like this
    batch:
      repository:
        isolationlevelforcreate: ISOLATION_READ_COMMITTED

Also the exception may come from multiple batch jobs starting at the same time. Try to separate their start times and make sure they do not overlap.
Reference:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/25373
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48211928/175554
https://stackoverflow.com/a/64429710/175554


thanks for your reply. I have already used @Transactional but same error shown

can you put a small reproducer in github ? I can show you in code easier.

Hi here is the github link : https://github.com/enamul95/spring-batch-3.git @ozkanpakdil

it some time run smoth but it shows error.

I update data in step 1  after read for processing to stop other batch getting same data using procedure
