# scheduled jobs in batch application sometimes throw error

Tags: spring-batch, spring-batch-tasklet

I have a scheduler to schedule the jobs to run at a particular time. It contains approx 10 jobs to be run according to given cron expression. But sometimes some jobs fails giving exception "CannotSerializeTransactionException" and it is happening most frequently.

We have a platformTransactionManager which is returned to jobRepository which is dynamically created.

```
@Bean(name = "jpaTransactionManager")
    @Primary
    public PlatformTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager() throws SQLException{
        return new JpaTransactionManager(this.entityManagerFactory().getObject());
    }
```

So, I cannot set the isolation level for jobRepository. How to solve the issue now to resolve the error.
I have tried to look into the issue but I could not understand what is causing the jobs to fail.

````
    public void dailyStatusEmailNotificationJobRun() throws JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException, JobRestartException, JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException, JobParametersInvalidException{
        final JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder().addDate(START_TIME, new Date(System.currentTimeMillis())).toJobParameters();
        jobLauncher.run(dailyStatusEmailNotifyJob, jobParameters);

    }```

I expect the jobs should run correctly.

The error trace thrown is:
[batch] 05.07.2019 09:00:00.270 [OUT] [ERROR] [            ] [         ] org.springframework.scheduling.support.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task.
org.springframework.dao.CannotSerializeTransactionException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [INSERT into BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE(JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME, JOB_KEY, VERSION) values (?, ?, ?, ?)]; ORA-08177: can't serialize access for this transaction
; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: ORA-08177: can't serialize access for this transaction

    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:267) ~[spring-jdbc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:73) ~[spring-jdbc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:660) ~[spring-jdbc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:909) ~[spring-jdbc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:970) ~[spring-jdbc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:975) ~[spring-jdbc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcJobInstanceDao.createJobInstance(JdbcJobInstanceDao.java:115) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.createJobExecution(SimpleJobRepository.java:135) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor174.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317) ~[spring-aop-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) ~[spring-aop-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281) ~[spring-tx-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.AbstractJobRepositoryFactoryBean$1.invoke(AbstractJobRepositoryFactoryBean.java:172) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207) ~[spring-aop-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy181.createJobExecution(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:125) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor172.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317) ~[spring-aop-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) ~[spring-aop-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:127) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207) ~[spring-aop-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy206.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at at.sitsolutions.services.ftm.batch.service.scheduler.batchScheduler.dailyStatusEmailNotificationJobRun(batchScheduler.java:229) ~[ftm-batch-service-2.11.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
````

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Batch ORA-08177: can't serialize access for this transaction when running single job, SERIALIZED isolation level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22364432/spring-batch-ora-08177-cant-serialize-access-for-this-transaction-when-running)

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine  Here i do not have jobRepository to set the isolationLevel. 
Just PlatformTransactionManager is returned.
So, where to set the isolation_level?

Comment: The isolation level is a property of the `JobRepositoryFactoryBean`. You need to use this factory bean to set a custom isolation level. It is shown in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38148496/5019386 (could be done in Java config too).