# Database connection in spring batch

Tags: oracle, jdbc, spring-batch

Problem Statement:Getting error

> ORA-08177: can't serialize access for this transaction in spring batch application.
>   Error:org.springframework.dao.CannotSerializeTransactionException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [INSERT into BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE(JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME, JOB_KEY, VERSION) values (?, ?, ?, ?)]; ORA-08177: can't serialize access for this transaction
>   ; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: ORA-08177: can't serialize access for this transaction

I am using only one instance of datasource throughout spring batch application.
Datasource:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("legal")
@Bean
   static DataSource dataSourceLegal() {
    DriverManagerDataSource driverManagerDataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    driverManagerDataSource.setUrl(url);
    driverManagerDataSource.setUsername(userName);
    driverManagerDataSource.setPassword(pwd);
    driverManagerDataSource.setDriverClassName(driver);
    return driverManagerDataSource;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Batch ORA-08177: can't serialize access for this transaction when running single job, SERIALIZED isolation level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22364432/spring-batch-ora-08177-cant-serialize-access-for-this-transaction-when-running)