# Spring Batch ORA-08177: can't serialize access for this transaction

Tags: spring-batch

We are facing ORA-08177 issue sometimes. Even Though we change isolation level with batch.repository.isolationlevelforcreate=ISOLATION_READ_COMMITTED, It did not solve the problem.

Spring batch version is 4.1.2.RELEASE.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Batch ORA-08177: can't serialize access for this transaction when running single job, SERIALIZED isolation level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22364432/spring-batch-ora-08177-cant-serialize-access-for-this-transaction-when-running)

Comment: What's the present Oracle SID parameter value of DEFERRED_SEGMENT_CREATION? Do you see this problem happening if Oracle SID is created with DEFERRED_SEGMENT_CREATION parameter value set to FALSE?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [Spring Boot 2.7 or later](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.7-Release-Notes#miscellaneous), you can use the [spring.batch.jdbc.isolation-level-for-create](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.integration.spring.batch.jdbc.isolation-level-for-create) application property to set the desired transaction isolation level:

> The transaction isolation level of Spring Batch can be configured using the `spring.batch.jdbc.isolation-level-for-create` property.

For example, you can add the following property to your `application.properties` file:

```
spring.batch.jdbc.isolation-level-for-create=read_committed
```