# How to ensure that a Spring Batch Job-Instance gets executed exactly once when started concurrently on two (or multiple) nodes

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

We have two replicas of a Spring Boot backend running on two nodes.
The two backends concurrently start the same job instance. The job instance is identified using a parameter 'execution-date', which is a Java date 'rounded down to the beginning of the minute', i.e. seconds, milliseconds are set to zero. The code for executing the job instance:

```java
try {
    var executionDate = DateTimeUtils.roundDownToBeginOfMinute(new Date());
    var params = new HashMap<String, JobParameter>();
    params.put("execution-date", new JobParameter(executionDate, true));

    var jobExecution = jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters(params));
    ...

} catch (JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException | JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException e) {
    log.info("Job already executed on other node");
} catch (Exception e) {
    log.error("Unexpected exception", e);
}
```

Using this approach we encountered the following problem:

- replica 1 gets a org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException, as expected
- replica 2, 327ms later, reports:   org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [INSERT into BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE(JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME, JOB_KEY, VERSION) values (?, ?, ?, ?)]; ORA-00001: unique constraint (APP.JOB_INST_UN) violated
- **none of the replicas executed the job**

**How would you proceed in our situation?**

Our framework and DB versions:

- Spring Boot: 2.7.15
- spring-core: 5.3.29
- spring-batch-core: 4.3.9
- DB: Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production Version 19.19.0.0.0, Case sensitivity: plain=upper, delimited=exact

As proposed by https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/28802, we set `spring.batch.jdbc.isolation-level-for-create=SERIALIZABLE`, but now we have different undesirable behavior:

- in several cases both replicas get `CannotSerializeTransactionException` on attempting to start a job (the job itself does nothing in the DB) and **none of them executes it**
- in one case we had the same job-instance executed twice, we see two entries with the same job-parameters in the job repository (tables BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION, BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_PARAMS)

We built a workaround (DB-table with UniqueConstraint on column 'execution-date') that works.

But actually, we would really like to employ Spring Batch job repository as a lock for concurrent job-executions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Using this approach we encountered the following problem:

> replica 1 gets a org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException, as expected
> replica 2, 327ms later, reports: org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [INSERT into BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE(JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME, JOB_KEY, VERSION) values (?, ?, ?, ?)]; ORA-00001: unique constraint (APP.JOB_INST_UN) violated
> none of the replicas executed the job
> How would you proceed in our situation?

That should not be the case. Using the `SERIALIZABLE` isolation level is the way to go, which seems to have fixed your issue as you described.

> we set spring.batch.jdbc.isolation-level-for-create=SERIALIZABLE, but now we have different undesirable behavior:

> in several cases both replicas get CannotSerializeTransactionException on attempting to start a job (the job itself does nothing in the DB) and none of them executes it

> in one case we had the same job-instance executed twice, we see two entries with the same job-parameters in the job repository (tables BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION, BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_PARAMS)

You might need to increase the `INITRANS` parameter to resolve those issues, see [Spring Batch ORA-08177: can't serialize access for this transaction when running single job, SERIALIZED isolation level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22364432/spring-batch-ora-08177-cant-serialize-access-for-this-transaction-when-running)

Comment: Oracle's deferred segment creation may also play a role, see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/1127. The DDL for Oracle was updated to change the segment creation to IMMEDIATE: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/commit/fac59e6319f3deb54ce96890b706278ab6ac9aab

Comment: Thanks for the general guidance and the clues regarding `INITRANS` and segment creation. `select ini_trans from user_tables where table_name = 'BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION';` returns 1 i.e. the default. So this is a good lead. I'll get back here when I have more information.