Caused by: Error : 8177, Position : 0, Sql = INSERT INTO BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE(JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME, JOB_KEY, VERSION) in spring batch 5
I am using spring batch 5 using oracle.  I have more than 30 batches from multiple projects running using the database. But it shows below error:
            error code [8177]; ORA-08177: can't serialize access for this transaction

        org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [INSERT INTO BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE(JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME, JOB_KEY, VERSION)
            VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
        ]; SQL state [72000]; error code [8177]; ORA-08177: can't serialize access for this transaction

            at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.translateException(JdbcTemplate.java:1573)
            at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:667)
            at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:960)
            at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:1015)
            at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:1020)
            at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcJobInstanceDao.createJobInstance(JdbcJobInstanceDao.java:157)
            at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.createJobExecution(SimpleJobRepository.java:169)
            at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor32.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
            at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
            at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:196)
            at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
            at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
            at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:391)
            at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
            at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
            at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.AbstractJobRepositoryFactoryBean.lambda$getObject$0(AbstractJobRepositoryFactoryBean.java:204)
            at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
            at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:244)
            at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy124.createJobExecution(Unknown Source)
            at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:145)
            at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.TaskExecutorJobLauncher.run(TaskExecutorJobLauncher.java:59)
            at com.citylive.prepaidcard.config.ScheduledJobBean.perform(ScheduledJobBean.java:62)
            at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor36.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
            at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:84)
            at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
            at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:96)
            at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
            at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
            at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
            at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
            at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
            at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
        Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-08177: can't serialize access for this transaction

            at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:629)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:563)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1150)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:770)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:298)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:497)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:151)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1051)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeSQLStatement(OracleStatement.java:1530)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1310)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3745)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3917)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3896)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:991)
            at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61)
            at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
            at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.lambda$update$2(JdbcTemplate.java:965)
            at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:648)
            ... 34 more
        Caused by: Error : 8177, Position : 0, Sql = INSERT INTO BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE(JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME, JOB_KEY, VERSION)
            VALUES (:1 , :2 , :3 , :4 )
        , OriginalSql = INSERT INTO BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE(JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME, JOB_KEY, VERSION)
            VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
        , Error Msg = ORA-08177: can't serialize access for this transaction

            at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:636)
            ... 51 more


My application.properties
    spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
    spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/test
    spring.datasource.username=test
    spring.datasource.password=test

    logging.level.root=INFO
    logging.level.org.hibernate.stat=DEBUG
    logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG

    spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size = 2000
    spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_updates=true

    spring.batch.job.chunk.size=10


    batch-schduled-time=0 */1 * * * ?


    spring.batch.jdbc.schema=never
    spring.batch.jdbc.initialize-schema=never
    spring.datasource.hikari.isolation=SERIALIZABLE
    spring.datasource.hikari.maximumPoolSize=10


Job Schedule
    @Component
    @Slf4j
    public class ScheduledJobBean {
        @Autowired
        JobLauncher jobLauncher;

        @Autowired
        PrepaidCardJob prepaidCardJob;


        @Autowired
        private  JobRepository jobRepository;


        @Scheduled(cron = "${batch-schduled-time}")
        public void perform() throws Exception
        {

            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EE, dd MMM yyyy, hh:mm a");
            String scheduleStartDate = dateFormat.format(new Date());

            JobExecution execution = null;
            JobExecution executionTransaction = null;

               try {

                    JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder()
                            .addLong("startAtPrepaidCardtep1", System.currentTimeMillis())
                            .toJobParameters();

                    execution = jobLauncher.run(prepaidCardJob.createPrepaidCard(), jobParameters);

                    log.info(Constants.batchTag + "{} Prepaid Card  batch {} Step1 existStatus: "+execution.getExitStatus().getExitCode());

                } catch (JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException | JobRestartException |
                         JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException |
                         JobParametersInvalidException ex) {
                    // Handle exceptions if necessary
                    log.error(Constants.batchTag + "{} Prepaid Card  batch {} Step1 {} execution {} JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException | JobRestartException | JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException | JobParametersInvalidException message: "+ex.getMessage());
                    ex.printStackTrace();

                }catch (Exception ex) {
                    log.error(Constants.batchTag + "{} Prepaid Card  batch {} Step1 execution {} error: "+ex.getMessage());
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                    log.error(ex.getMessage());

                }



        }
    }


Job:
    @Component
    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    @Slf4j
    public class PrepaidCardJob {


        private final ProcessorStep1 batchProcessorStep1;
        private final WriterStep1 batchWriterStep1;

        private final PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;
        private final JobRepository jobRepository;


        @Autowired
        private JobExecutionListenerStep1 jobExecutionListenerStep1;

        private final TransactionSPcall transactionSPcall;

        @Value("${spring.batch.job.chunk.size}")
        private Integer chunkSize;


        public Job createPrepaidCard(){
            return new JobBuilder("PREPAID_CARD-STEP1", jobRepository)
                    .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                    .start(step1())
                    .build();




        }

        private Step step1(){

            return new StepBuilder("step1", jobRepository)
                    .<String, String> chunk(chunkSize, transactionManager)
                    .reader(new ReaderStep1())
                    .processor(batchProcessorStep1)
                    .writer(batchWriterStep1)
                    .build();
        }


    }


Batch beans:
        @Configuration
    @EnableBatchProcessing
    public class BatchBean {

        @Bean
        public ProcessorStep1 batchProcessorStep1() {
            return new ProcessorStep1();
        }

        @Bean
        public WriterStep1 batchWriterStep1() {
            return new WriterStep1();
        }

        @Bean
        public ProcessorStep2 batchProcessorStep2() {
            return new ProcessorStep2();
        }

        @Bean
        public WriterStep2 batchWriterStep2() {
            return new WriterStep2();
        }


        @Bean
        public JobRepository jobRepository(DataSource dataSource, PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) throws Exception {
            JobRepositoryFactoryBean jobRepositoryFactoryBean = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
            jobRepositoryFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
            jobRepositoryFactoryBean.setTransactionManager(transactionManager);
            jobRepositoryFactoryBean.setIsolationLevelForCreate("ISOLATION_SERIALIZABLE");
            jobRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
            return jobRepositoryFactoryBean.getObject();
        }

        @Bean
        public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(DataSource dataSource) {
            return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource);
        }

    }



What is the wrong of my code? Other batch which is running shows above error too.
Please help me

Does this answer your question? Spring Batch ORA-08177: can't serialize access for this transaction when running single job, SERIALIZED isolation level

@seenukarthi I have alter table alter table BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION INITRANS 3 and also alter other table started with batch_ ... but it shows same error

@seenukarthi I have added spring.batch.jdbc.isolation-level-for-create=read_committed to application.properties. same error shows...Is there any other options to solve the problem?

@seenukarthi I am struggling for this error..but there is no solution found

@seenukarthi I have tried all on  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22364432/spring-batch-ora-08177-cant-serialize-access-for-this-transaction-when-running . But same error happen after two or 3 schedule later. some times it some time it running more than one hour. but error happens.. please help me

I have solved the problem using below configuration:

Here is bean config:
   @Configuration
  public class BatchBean {  
    @Bean
    public JobRepository jobRepository(DataSource dataSource, PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) throws Exception {
        JobRepositoryFactoryBean jobRepositoryFactoryBean = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
        jobRepositoryFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
        jobRepositoryFactoryBean.setTransactionManager(transactionManager);
        jobRepositoryFactoryBean.setIsolationLevelForCreate("ISOLATION_READ_COMMITTED");
        jobRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
        return jobRepositoryFactoryBean.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
        return transactionManager;
    }
 }


Add below properties in  application.properties
spring.datasource.hikari.isolation=READ_COMMITTED
spring.batch.jdbc.schema=always
spring.batch.jdbc.initialize-schema=always
spring.datasource.hikari.maximumPoolSize=10



